# Could Not Load Textures From Assets In FXGL

Tags: javafx, assets, fxgl

I want to make a 2D game for a project that belongs to my university. So I decided to use JavaFX and FXGL library. I got a test basic project from [FXGL Git repository](https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGLGames/tree/master/Drop) and tried to run it. When I run this project FXGL warns that it could not load texture `bucket.png`. Here is the complete log message:
`19:54:36.901 [FXGL Background Thread 1 ] WARN  FXGLAssetLoaderServi - Failed to load texture bucket.png Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Asset "/assets/textures/bucket.png" was not found!`
Here is my project structure:
[image]
 I use Oracle JDK 14, OpenJFX 15, Gradle as build tool and IntelliJ IDEA 
 
 And module-info.java class:

```
module hellofx {
    requires com.almasb.fxgl.all;

    exports org.openjfx;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add an `opens assets.textures;` directive to your module-info file?

Answer (score 3):

After spending several hours for finding the problem, as @Slaw mentioned in the comments section, I found that module descriptor file (module-info.java) should be changed to the following format:

```
open module hellofx {
    requires com.almasb.fxgl.all;
}
```

Comment: Then your problem had to do with "resource encapsulation", described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).